# Permission denied (public key): Multiple Repositories and RSA Keys Using Github

Tags: git, ssh, github, rsa

I am getting the Permission denied (public key) error when making 
an ssh git@github.com request. My feeling is that this is because 
it can't find my .ssh folder. Here is the background on what I have
done thus far:

I previously configured github to work 
with my a repository : repo1. I followed
the newbie guide on the github site and 
set my repo up as:

/home/CodeSherpa/repo1/

with security stuff here:

/home/CodeSherpa/.ssh

I configured id_rsa and id_rsa.pub
according to the guide and put the 
public key on github in my public
keys. I then tested with

ssh git@github.com

and did some push/pull/etc commands
and everything worked just fine.

Now, I want to add a few more repositories. 
I have moved my local directory structure 
around to look like this:

/home/CodeSherpa/repos/

*repo1
*repo2
*repo3

And I have set up / configured the matching repositories on github.

I am the Admin and should have access to everything. I want to give 
one developer access to repo1 & repo2 but NOT repo3 and another developer
access to all repos.

**MY CURRENT PROBLEM IS** that when I try to initialize the new repositories
on my local filesystem I keep getting:

"Permission denied (public key)"
(using ssh git@github.com)

**MY QUESTION IS** do I have to have a local RSA key for each new repository? 
Currently, my .ssh folder is where I originally set it up for my first repo:

/home/CodeSherpa/.ssh

Do I need to do this:

```
> /home/CodeSherpa/repos/repo1/.ssh/id_rsa
> /home/CodeSherpa/repos/repo2/.ssh/id_rsa
> /home/CodeSherpa/repos/repo3/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And then set up three unique public keys for each repo 
on github?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you need only one key per user, not per repository. My suggestion would be:

- delete all the keys in your computer
- delete all your keys in github
- follow the process again, *just once*

**BUT** If your intention is to have one user per repository, then you'll need one ssh key per user. To do this:

- follow the instructions in github 3 times, and give each key a different file name.
- when you want to use one of those keys, run `ssh-add [path_to_user_1_key]`
  ** from this point, you'll connect to github as user_1
- If you need to connect as a different user, for example user_2, run `ssh-add -D` and `ssd-add [path_to_user_2_key]`

As an example, I use the same ssh key for github and bitbucket, and I have a few repos on each server.

Comment: Augusto - I am not sure. Here is what I want to do: 
I am the Admin and should have access to everything. I want to give 
one developer access to repo1 & repo2 but NOT repo3 and another developer access to all repos. Should I be following your suggestion that follows BUT...?

Comment: Are you doing this with the "Organizations" feature of GitHub? If so, why not use separate teams for these users and slice/dice access control that way?

Comment: no, it is a personal account. I am currently looking into Organizations - good suggestion. If it isn't too expensive i'll do that...

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but I had the idea that you can give permissions per repository to other people... I even been given permission to commit on some repos, but not on all the repos of the owners. Sorry that I can't confirm this (or if it's free) as github is crawling for me.

Answer (score 2):

- In github (in most places really) a ssh key is tied to a user account (because its used to verify/authenticate to github that you are really who you claim to be), not to a repo.
- You should be able to add any other github user as a collaborator to any of your projects.
- Adding collaborators is how control access to your projects on github. You don't need to create multipal ssh keys for this.
- You can add a collaborator to your project by going to "Repository Administration" -> "Collaborators".